# what is the meaning of isolation of transformer between i/p to o/p is 1 kv & mains supply to body/chassis is 2 kv

Tags: power-supply, transformer, isolation

I have to design a transformer with isolation factor as follows:-

1. Isolation between i/p & o/p is 1Kv
2. Isolation between mains supply to chassis is 2.5Kv

How to calculate these isolation factors

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What’s there to calculate? You choose materials accordingly and do hi pot tests in production.

Comment: Your question does not match the title, it is meaningless.

Comment: @neeteen09: 'k' for kilo, 'V' for volt. Capitals, punctuation and question marks matter.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a specific question, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage isolation ratings are insulation ratings. The voltage isolation rating between between input and output or primary and secondary is the voltage that can safely be applied between the primary winding and the secondary winding. The voltage isolation betweens the mains supply and the chassis is the voltage that can be safely applied between the mains terminals and the chassis.

The winding wire insulation only needs to withstand the voltage between one turn of a winding and another turn that it contacts. Additional insulation may need to be used between layers of windings and between the primary and secondary coils. Additional insulation may also be needed between the windings and the steel core and between the windings and leads and the steel enclosure or chassis that supports the core.

The connection of the leads to the windings and any fixed terminals will also need insulation. Various types of flexible and rigid or semi-flexible insulation may be needed. Some transformers may have insulating "varnish" applied to the windings after they have been wound.

Answer (score 1):

The different isolation voltages relate to different thicknesses of insulation.

The 2.5kV mains to chassis means you need to use a bobbin/former made from thick plastic.

The 1kV input to output means that thinner insulation is required between the primary and secondary windings. This would tend to be built up from several layers of tape.